# Select most popular hour per country based on number of sales

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I want to get the most popular hour for each country based on max value of count(id) which tells how many purchases were made.

I've tried getting the max value of purchases and converted the timestamp into hours, but it always returns each hour for each country when I want only a single hour (the one with most purchases) per country.

The table is like:

```
id  |  country  |  time  
1   |    AE     |  19:20:00.00000
1   |    AE     |  20:13:00.00000
3   |    GB     |  23:17:00.00000
4   |    IN     |  10:23:00.00000
6   |    IN     |  02:01:00.00000
7   |    RU     |  05:54:00.00000
2   |    RU     |  16:34:00.00000
```

```
SELECT max(purchases), country, tss 
FROM (
    SELECT time_trunc(time, hour) AS tss,
           count(id) as purchases,
           country
    FROM spending
    WHERE dt > date_sub(current_date(), interval 30 DAY)
    GROUP BY tss, country
)
GROUP BY tss, country
```

Expected output:

```
amount of purchases | Country | Most popular Hour
       34           |    GB   | 16:00
       445          |    US   | 21:00
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Does a day have 24th hour?

Comment: Error is that it returns 24 values for each country, when it should only return the most popular hour @ErsinGülbahar

Comment: Last hour is 23:00 @SalmanA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions along with group by. Notice that it uses `RANK` function so, for example, if one particular country has same amount of sales at 11AM and 2PM it'll return both hours for that country.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT country
         , time_trunc(time, hour) AS hourofday
         , COUNT(id) AS purchases
         , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM t
    GROUP BY country, time_trunc(time, hour)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Worked otherwise, but it only returned one row that had one country. The output should have a row for each country.